# Installing ADB Driver (Manually?)

Tags: adb, windows, usb-drivers

I'm trying to install ADB drivers for my phone on Windows 8. Previously on Windows 7 I used a driver that is not supported on Win8 and also doesn't work.

- Debugging option is set.
- Version 4.0.4
- Sharp 106SH

Now, I've found a newer driver with the description:

1. Connect the terminal to the PC using a USB cable.
2. The Android Composite ADB Interface is detected, and the driver installation
   screen appears.
3. Select /usb_driver_SHARP/ for the driver storage location and install the driver.

My problem is that this dialog/screen never appears. Is it possible to make this dialog appear manually?

Comment: If the driver is not compatiple with Win8: have you tried Koush's [Universal ADB driver](http://adbdriver.com/)?

Comment: @Izzy: Yes I have. Didn't work.

Comment: Try installing http://pdanet.co/ on your computer. It is bundled with drivers for nearly all phones. You can uninstall the software after installing it, just use it to obtain the drivers.

Comment: @BryanDenny: Thanks for the suggestion of this interesting app. But my phone is not supported and does not get recognized.